# output filename from a different string

Tags: c++, file, text-files, filepath

hi i am having a bit of trouble with this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line;
    //const char* test = "connect";
    #define test "connect"
    string con("c:\\filepath\\%s.txt", test);
    ifstream file;
    file.open(con.c_str());
    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (file.good()) {
            getline(file, line);
            printf("setc %s\n", line.c_str());
            //cout << "setc " << line << endl;
        }
        file.close();
    } else
        cout << "Unable to open file";
    return 0;
}
```

could someone please tell me what i am going wrong

this is what i am after

'con' is meant to get its filename from 'test'

if you could help me i would appreciate it :)

Comment: The `<TAB>` key is usually located in the top left corner of the keyboard. Now that you know where to find it, nothing prevents you from using it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here are two:

```
std::string con1("c:\\filepath\\" test ".txt");
std::string con2("c:\\filepath\\" + std::string(test) + ".txt");
```

The initialization of `con1` requires that `test` becomes a string literal through macro expansion as it relies on the merging of of string literals. The second form is more general and `test` can be anything which can be converted to a `std::string`, e.g., a `char const*`.

Comment: thank you so much would you please tell me what form you used to do that? like what is the style for that kind of code

Comment: I prefer the second form because I don't use macros for constants. Of course, if you use `std::string const test("connect");` for the constant you directly add it.